# Hibernate with JPA ignoring @Formula

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I have a `Formula` defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity
{
    @Enumerated(value = javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING)
    @Transient
    @Formula(value = "select e.state from OTHER_ENTITY e")
    private State state;

    public State getState()
    {
        return this.state;
    }
//setter and another properties
}
```

But it is ignoring it.

Here is my `Persistence Unit`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url:3306/db" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The sql are generated without the `Formula`.

If I remove the `@Transient` the `JPA` tries to load the `state` column and then fails.

I want to calculate the state based on the state of another entity. That's why the I think a `Formula` works.

Thank you!

Udo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to map the state twice : once by adding annotations to the field, and once by adding annotations to the getter. Put all the annotations at the same place (and at the same place as the `@Id` annotation).

But this is really confusing. Your state is transient (meaning it's not mapped at all, and should not be read from the database), but it's also enumerated (why would Hibernate use this annotation since it's supposed to be transient), and a formula.

Finally, a formula is some piece of SQL that's added in every SQL that is used to load your entity. So it should not contain a select clause, or a from clause, but just a formula using some of the columns of the table itself. For example, suppose you have a table with a column `salary` and a column `bonus`, you could have a formula for a field `totalIncome` which would be 'bonus + salary'. But id doesn't go much further than that.

Comment: But if I want to do not declare a column in db, then the @Transient is neede?

Comment: No. Formula already says : this is not a column in DB, but a value that is computed from other ones. So Transient is not needed.

Comment: Then why does it fails to load the persistence unit due to that column being missing?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong then, but all the examples of Formula in the Hibernate documentation don't use the Transient annotation. And usually, Hibernate doesn't care about a missing column in the database until it tries loading or persisting somthing to the table.

Comment: Well, are they using JPA in their examples, I read all through the documentation and could not find a complete example using JPA. the thing is it keeps failing if the column is not there. Maybe is failing the JPA? +1 for your wise advises and clarification anyway

Comment: Hibernate is an implementation of JPA. And Formula is not a standard JPA annotation anyway.

Comment: That's why maybe JPA doesn't know about Formula and ignore it.

Comment: Hibernate **IS** JPA. It just provides more than the standard minimum that JPA specifies. JPA is just a specification. You never do JPA. You do JPA using Hibernate as implementation, or EclipseLink, or DataNucleus. But JPA is just a spec, a norm if you prefer.

Comment: @ssedano so how did you solve it? what was the rootcase of situation, when formula is used, but hibernate still looks for column in database?

Comment: I went with another approach altogether as as stated in the answer my state was not persisted. I cannot remember what was the exact solution thou.

Comment: I also encounter with this situation and I see with my eyes that for querying I don't need `@Transient` in mapping, and only `@Formula` is working. But if I try to persist the entity with only @Formula, will the column be taken into consideration and thus throw an exception because the column doesn't exist in table?

Comment: I tested, and found that when persisting, fields with `@Formula` and without `@Transient` will not cause problem. Entity persisted with success.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work. I think @Transient is making Hibernate ignore the attribute at all.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity
{
    // MAYBE YOU HAVE TO MOVE IT TO THE GETTER @Enumerated(value = javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING)
    // REMOVE THIS @Transient
    private State state;

    @Enumerated(value = javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING) // MOVED
    @Formula(value = "(select e.state from OtheEntity e)")
    public State getState()
    {
        return this.state;
    }
//setter and another properties
}
```

Comment: maybe better to add parenthesis around the `select` clause in `@Formula`?